". . . the thick belching chimneys sitting close to the countryside and the narrow lanes tell him he's in a different country"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part I, Aberfan, chapter 3)

He (William) reaches Merthyr Vale at 3.35 in the morning, the Lavery and Sons hearse loaded with 30 gallons of formaldehyde, embalming instruments and four child-sized coffins. He's already passed through two police blocks with the password , Sommers', the largest undertakers in Cardiff. Though his journey has been in the dark, the thick belching chimneys sitting close to the countryside and the narrow lanes tell him he's in a different country.

I don't have any idea what chimneys sitting close to the countryside could mean in this context. I understand what 'I sit close to William' mean. But can chimneys sit close to the countryside? It's a mystery to me actually.

I don't know enough about the particulars of the area, but it seems like the idea is that normally industrial plants would be normally be in an industrial area, with more separation from countryside.

Note that sitting here is metaphorical. As @AndyBonner says, it just means the industrial plants (represented by thick belching chimneys) are nearer to "the countryside" than the subject ("he") would expect if he was in his own native country. Presumably his native country is Wales, but I've no reason to suppose that in reality Wales maintains greater separation between industrial premises and the countryside than other countries, so it may be just "artistic license".

@FumbleFingers - I was 14 when Aberfan happened. A colliery spoil tip collapsed and engulfed the Pantglas area of Aberfan (a 'mining village'), hitting some houses, and the school, killing 144 people, including 5 teachers and 109 children (out of 240) in the school. One notable feature of the South Wales industrial landscape is how close together residential areas and factories, steelworks, coal mines, etc, are located. Much closer together than the more genteel residents of a city like Cardiff might be used to. I would see 'country' as a figure of speech.

A different kind of area. Someone from Surrey in England might feel they were in a 'different country' if they went to an industrial valley in the North, with belching chimneys, slag heaps, electric pylons, etc.

William's home is Birmingham, metropolitan county, West Midlands, England and he is driving from Nottingham (near Birmingham, 57 miles) to Aberfan, Wales - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberfan#:~:text=Aberfan%20(Welsh%20pronunciation%3A%20%5B%CB%8Cab%C9%9Br%CB%88van,town%20of%20Merthyr%20Tydfil%2C%20Wales.

"There is also a good deal of clunky writing throughout." - The Guardian.

@MichaelHarvey That sounds like the best answer we can get!

https://www.theguardian.com/theguardian/1966/oct/22/fromthearchive

I live in Bristol and go to Cardiff on the train about three times each month. I am very fond of Wales and the Welsh. I wonder if you might like How Green was my Valley by Richard Llewellyn?

@MichaelHarvey: You're quite right, of course - "another country" is as figurative as "sitting". I was only 12 when Aberfan happened, but I'm pretty sure we had a minute's silence in school assembly. But several years before that I remember playing on slagheaps in Lancashire that must have been within easy walking distance of the new council estate our northern relatives lived on, when we drove up from Sussex on holiday. So it's not like only the Welsh had nasty industry in their back yard.

Think about it a little bit: you are in a train, it's nightime, all you can see are the chimneys full of smoke coming out of them in the distance and they look like they are sitting close the countryside that lies beyond. A little imagination helps. In English, metaphors like this abound. This kind of thing except with more visible countryside: https://www.mediastorehouse.co.uk/uig/history/britain/industrialisation-c1925-factory-chimneys-pouring-9780275.html

@FumbleFingers - I am what my partner from Wigan calls a 'southern jessie', and I was always, in my youth, taken aback by how close people up north lived to mills and factories. My grandma near Derby lived very near to a huge power station.

@FumbleFingers - maybe worth clarifying for non-UK readers that, in the UK, the word 'country' can have multiple, negotiable/controversial meanings. It can be used with the intended meaning of 'nation state', or 'province'. The four parts of the UK are very often called 'countries', but some people like to call the whole UK 'this country', and I recall Captain Terence O'Neill calling Northern Ireland 'this country' in the 1970s. Let's not forget LP Hartley's remark that 'the past is a foreign country' (where, famously 'they do things differently').

@ Lambie - Thank you. Yes, I thought it over and over again and I got an idea of its meaning like you. But my problem is I don't know if those ideas are correct and if the native speaker doesn't associate any other ideas with these words. Yes, you as a native speaker know the correct meaning right away. And if I as a non-native speaker have questions like this downvoted I'm deterred from checking back the meaning, actually.

sit there means "to be located, to be situated".

The house sits well back from the road.


The town sits at the foot of a steep hill covered by vineyards.

P.S. close to the countryside is something of a fixed phrase.  You will often see it in real estate listings that say things like "... in a seaside town yet close to the countryside". It means "not far from rural areas (with open fields, vistas, and natural beauty)."  So the connotation is of a stark contrast with the ugliness of "belching chimneys".

And the industrial plants are located close to green fields.

And the particular context of Aberfan, these are in the Welsh Valleys: industrial towns that run along the bottom of the valley and so are long and thin, with the rural hills between them. The towns are shaped like a snake, so the countryside is always near.

@JamesK - South Wales is one of the world's least likely and most extraordinary industrial landscapes.  There is a road that runs along the top, past the ends of all of them, called the Heads of the Valleys Road, that is as spectacular as any I have seen in Europe.
